# AngularJS consumes JAX-RS rest web service

Tags: java, angularjs, json, web-services, rest

This is the first time that I am using a Java back-end for my web application. I have a Jax-rs webservice that I am trying to consumes with my AngularJS app

**AngularJS call**

```
$http({
    url : REST_END_POINT + '/checkuser',
    method : "GET",
    data : {
        'userId' : credentials.username,
        'pwd' : credentials.password
    },
    dataType : "json",
    headers : {
        "Content-Type" : "application/json"
    }
});
```

**Webservice**

```
@GET
@Produces("application/json")
@Consumes("application/json")
@Path("checkuser/")
public string getCheckUser(@QueryParam("userId") String userId, @QueryParam("pwd") String pwd){
    try{
        if(port != null){
            boolean result = port.checkUser(userId, pwd);
            return new java.lang.Boolean(result).toString();
        }
    }catch(Exception ex){
        //TODO
    }
    return null;
}
```

Both `userId` and `pwd` are always `null`

With Firebug I can see that data contains

```
Object{
    userId="aaa",
    pwd="aa"
}
```

I also tried with `JSON.stringify` which send those data :

```
"{"userId":"aaa","pwd":"aa"}"
```

Comment: use an object with fields userId and pwd and not `@QueryParam` annotations. This is not to be used when you consume a json.

Comment: This was automatically generated by NetBeans. Is there another way to send json simply by specifying the parameter ? Not via an object ?

Comment: object will be a java class object whose fields will be mapped to json's fields. what `rest` library are you using?

Comment: If i understand it correctly at one hand you say that data is send correctly but at another backend say that data values are null.
I would try to open my browser dev tools and check inside of network tab what are you actualy sending to backend in your request. It helped me many times :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe that the way you are trying to access your userID and pwd is incorrect, you are using the @QueryParam which would look for the userID and pwd as query parameters of the GET request like so:

http://myservice:port/checkuser?userId=myuserid&pwd=pass

if you change your GET request to

```
$http({
url : REST_END_POINT + '/checkuser',
method : "GET",
params : {
    'userId' : credentials.username,
    'pwd' : credentials.password
},
dataType : "json",
headers : {
    "Content-Type" : "application/json"
}
});
```

Then you should have more luck.

However I wouldn't advise this method as it could be insecure. I'd instead look at trying to utilize an existing authentication system rather than rolling your own as these existing authentication systems will be far more secure.

Comment: so, is there a meaning for `datatype: json` with this approach?

Comment: Thanks ! It works ! I understand the security point but it is an old application and I cannot change the webservice...

Comment: @Apostolos Indeed there is no need to use neither dataType nor headers (I tried it)

Comment: I have another method which use `JAXBElement<User> user` as parameter. Should I do the same and send all the variable of user as JSON ?

Comment: @Forbsey1 What are the existing authentication systems ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use Jackson api for converting json to/ from Java objects.

Jackson contains simple mapper methods to implicitly map your json properties to Java class member variables.

Instead of @querypram use a Java class having fields as userId and pwd